# wordpress disable login for unverified user

Tags: users, login, user-registration, wp-signup

I have buy a theme form marketplace. This page is auto login after registration. I want to disable auto registration after login and without approving user by admin user can't login. How can do that? What is the function for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this below any plugins. It's a free version. Based on the admin & email approve customer allowed to login

https://wordpress.org/plugins/new-user-approve/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-approve-user/

Comment: I don't think that plugin recommendations are considered as answers in here...